# Exclude match in Regular Expression c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to exclude a specific string when it is contained in an expression:

**Example:**

```
myurl.htm = exclude

myurl = include
```

I tried this one : `([a-z0-9]+)(?!.htm)`
But looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: I read the question 5 times and it is still not clear for me..

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you add more examples?

Comment: So are periods not allowed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
([a-z0-9]+)(?!^\.htm)
```

You had two errors in your expression:

1. You have to escape the dot `.` with a backslash because it means "*matches any character (except newline)*" unescaped.
2. You have to add a `^` to prevent cutting of the last character.

You can test your expression on this website: https://regex101.com/

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch("myurl.htm", "([a-z0-9]+)(?!^\\.htm)")` returns true…

Comment: Than you just have to add $ at the end of the expression.
 --> ([a-z0-9]+)(?!\.htm)$

Comment: `^` matches the start of the string, therefore the lookahead assertion is completely useless.